# How can I extract the rendering as images on the hard disk instead a video file?

Tags: animation

Now I'm using ffmpeg in the Output properties and it's making one video file format.
How can I make that it will also create 120 images of all the frames on the hard disk type png ?

When I'm doing CTRL + F12 it's rendering one video file on the hard disk but I want also that it will create 120 images of the frames.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

change the file format to whatever image format you wanna use. Then when you're done with that you can convert the images into a video using the built in video editor

Answer (score 0):

In the compositor you can add a file output node, that way on top of rendering the video, you blender will save each frame as a single image file in the format you want.

[image]